# css html positioning web-design

Tags: html, css, web, positioning, sticky

I'm having some difficulties trying to avoid an undesired scrolling effect in CSS.

The fact is that I'm using `position: sticky` and `position: -webkit-sticky` for a site and I've noticed that on iOS browsers (including Firefox and Safari) and on desktop with Safari the positioning of `sticky` works just fine, but while scrolling down it gets some strange flickering on the sticky element, like if it's going down for a moment and then it gets back on top positioning sticky.

I'm linking a gif to show you the problem.
[Link to gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AigyX.gif)

Is there a solution to this? Maybe some touch classes that has to be added on the sticky container?

Thanks

**EDIT**
This is the code.
I have one major container named `container` with there properties:

```
     height: 100vh;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

then an inner section named `area`:

```
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top:0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
```

then an `inner-section` inside the `area`:

```
height: 2000px;
```

Comment: Ciao! I don't have this problem, can you post some relevant code?

Comment: hey! just edited the question with the code